# Finding the formula for probability in a sample space

Tags: probability

From Finan's probability book $13.13$

*Consider the experiment of rolling a fair die twice. Let $X(i, j) = max\{i, j\}$.
Find a formula of $P(X = x)$ in terms of $x$.*

I know how to find the probabilities by making a table of all $36$ sample spaces and then just counting the rows and columns:

(1, 1),(1, 2),(1, 3),(1, 4),(1, 5),(1, 6),

(2, 1),(2, 2),(2, 3),(2, 4),(2, 5),(2, 6),

(3, 1),(3, 2),(3, 3),(3, 4),(3, 5),(3, 6),

(4, 1),(4, 2),(4, 3),(4, 4),(4, 5),(4, 6),

(5, 1),(5, 2),(5, 3),(5, 4),(5, 5),(5, 6),

(6, 1),(6, 2),(6, 3),(6, 4),(6, 5),(6, 6)

but the question is asking for a a formula.

The answer is $2x−1
\over36$.

I understand that the formula works, but how was it originally derived? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to compute $P(X≤m)$. For that we just need both die to come up no greater than $m$ so $$P(X≤m)=\left(\frac m6\right)^2$$

But then we can read off $$P(X=m)=P(X≤m)-P(x≤m-1)=\left(\frac m6\right)^2-\left(\frac {m-1}6\right)^2=\frac {2m-1}{36}$$  as desired.

Worth noting:  it's not hard to generalize this to the case of more than $2$ dice.

Comment: Sorry, can you please explain $P(X≤m)$ ?

Comment: That means "the probability that the max is less than or equal to $m$".   $m$ is what you called $x$, I just don't like using both $X$ and $x$.